# What's the difference between NOON states and cat states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I am wondering which is the exact definition of NOON states and cat states and which is the difference between them. Is one a special kind of the other?

Answer (score 0):

> Is one a special kind of the other?

Yes. NOON states are a specific kind of Schrödinger-cat state. The term "cat state" implies a roughly-equal superposition of distinguishably-different state, and NOON states are cat states where the two states in superposition are specifically the $|N,0\rangle$ and $|0,N\rangle$ states.

Comment: Thanks. So, can you please make an example of a cat state which is not a NOON state?

Comment: Have you tried starting with [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_state)?